# Magic with a K, summer camp and crystals

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to find this book series for a long time and have all but given up. Maybe you can help.

The series I'm thinking of is for young adults. It's about kids who are magical. I think they spell it magick (with a k - although I don't remember if there was a c or not). They used crystals to focus it. They go to a summer camp, and at one point, one of the kids gets stuck in his crystal.

I don't remember any other plot details. Hope that's enough...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be *[The Magickers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magickers)* by Emily Drake? [This review](http://blogs.uww.edu/onceuponablog/2012/02/23/magick-and-adventure/) sounded like your description, but the content of the link is no longer available.

Here is the Wikipedia summary of the first book:

> In the magickers eleven-year-old Jason's dreams of attending a summer soccer camp are dashed when he is injured during tryouts. Just as he accepts that he must spend the summer with his grandmother, he receives an invitation to Camp Ravenwyng, a summer camp for the Talented. Jason is skeptical when he meets the oddly dressed counselors who usher him onto the camp bus. When the bus appears to crash into the side of a mountain only to come out on the other side of a dark tunnel, Jason realizes that this summer will not be ordinary. Jason eventually learns that his talent is to be a Magickers—one who can focus for good the force of magic that exists in the earth. His new talents are tested severely as he and his new friends must save the camp from certain destruction by the Dark Hand, those who would use magic for evil.

Comment: That's exactly it! I recognized the cover as soon as I saw it. Thanks.